# Create new properties based on embedded array elements in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have this kind of document

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("573342930348ce88ff1685f3"),
    "presences" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("573342930348ce88ff1685f2"), 
            "createdAt" : NumberLong(1458751869000) 
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("573342930348ce88ff1685f5"), 
            "createdAt" : NumberLong(1458751885000)
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("573342930348ce88ff1685f7"), 
            "createdAt" : NumberLong(1458751894000)
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I extract first and last presences element to new properties firstPresence and lastPresence like this?

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("573342930348ce88ff1685f3"),
    "firstPresence": {
        "_id" : ObjectId("573342930348ce88ff1685f2"), 
        "createdAt" : NumberLong(1458751869000) 
    },
    "lastPresence": {
        "_id" : ObjectId("573342930348ce88ff1685f7"), 
        "createdAt" : NumberLong(1458751894000)
    },
    "presences" : [
        ...
    ]
}
```

I want to use a query that can be applied to all documents in one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) your *presences* array to do the aggregation. Before grouping you can sort them by *createdAt* to utilize **$first** and **$last** operators.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { $unwind: "$presences" },
        { $sort: { "presences.createdAt": 1 } },
        { 
            $group: {
                _id: "$_id",
                "presences": { $push: "$presences" },
                "lastPresence": { $last: "$presences" },
                "firstPresence": { $first: "$presences" },
            } 
        },
        { $out : "collection" }
    ])
```

Last aggregation pipeline ([$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)) will replace existing collection.

Comment: It will replace my documents or create new ones?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that you want to project your data. If you need to replace existing collection you should add $out as a last step - just as I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to above mentioned description as a solution to it please try executing following aggregate query into MongoDB shell

```
   db.collection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $project: {

                first: {
                    $arrayElemAt: ["$presences", 0]
                },
                last: {
                    $arrayElemAt: ["$presences", -1]
                },
                presences: 1
            }
        },

    ]



);
```